# Writing large object into excel is taking hell out of time. Any way to fix this?

Tags: excel, datatable, c#-3.0, epplus

I have a predefined format of an excel file and am writing my object into that excel which is taking lot of time and the application is going into stale mode.

I am using EpPlus library.

Please find the code below and let me know if I can make things better.

```
    FileInfo fileInfo = new FileInfo(xslxpath);
    using (ExcelPackage excelPackage = new ExcelPackage(fileInfo))
    {
      int excelRow = 2;
      ExcelWorksheet worksheet1 = excelPackage.Workbook.Worksheets.First();
      foreach (var rows in objDetails)
      {
        worksheet1.Cells[excelRow, 1].Value = rows.ID.ToString();
        worksheet1.Cells[excelRow, 2].Value = rows.Name.ToString();
        worksheet1.Cells[excelRow, 3].Value = rows.Days.ToString();
        worksheet1.Cells[excelRow, 4].Value = rows.Amount.ToString();
        worksheet1.Cells[excelRow, 5].Value = rows.Reason.ToString();
        WriteToLogFile(LogFile, excelRow.ToString() + " " + rows.IPNumber.ToString());

        worksheet1.Cells.AutoFitColumns();
        excelRow++;
        WriteToLogFile(LogFile, excelRow.ToString() + " " + rows.IPNumber.ToString());
      }

      excelPackage.Save();
    }
```

Comment: What does the `WriteToLogFile` method do? And why do you call it twice per iteration with the same information? Consider taking this call out and put it into its own seperate iteration afterwards. And also move `worksheet1.Cells.AutoFitColumns()` to be called only once outside the iteration.

Comment: Log is just for testing purpose it will not for final product :). 
Taking the worksheet1.Cells.AutoFitColumns()  out does the work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
worksheet1.Cells.AutoFitColumns();
```

You should call this once after your loop, not for each and every line.

Comment: Is there a way to write into excel 97-2003 format(.xls) with better performance

Comment: npoi.dll can read/write .xls as well as .xlsx files. It's in github.

Also, try to load your data into the worksheet column x row, not row x column.

if you ever loaded data into Excel from a dataset using VBA, the COM library has a way to push a Datset into a Range (Range.CopyFromDataset), but you'll need to transpose it along the way, because the dataset's rows get added to excel columns otherwise.